# Find Documents not having String "stag" in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working with MongoDB, my documents have an image name. Some of my documents have string concat with image name e.g

**Image document without "stag" string concat with image name**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be79bc6f0fc699030b472"),
    "isPublished" : 1,
    "width" : 500,
    "height" : 341,
    "shared_by" : [],
    "saved_by" : [ 
        "5e0e01fcc6f0fc112953c05c", 
        "5e10091fc6f0fc19552773be", 
        "5e133a3ec6f0fc4e6b0cd5b4"
    ],
    "img" : "1577838487.png",
    "deploy_date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:28:11.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:28:11.000Z")
}
```

**Image document with "stag" string concat with image name**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0be79bc6f0fc699030b472"),
    "isPublished" : 1,
    "width" : 500,
    "height" : 341,
    "shared_by" : [],
    "saved_by" : [ 
        "5e0e01fcc6f0fc112953c05c", 
        "5e10091fc6f0fc19552773be", 
        "5e133a3ec6f0fc4e6b0cd5b4"
    ],
    "img" : "stag/1577838487.png",
    "deploy_date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:28:11.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:28:11.000Z")
}
```

I want to get all documents in which img field doesn't contain a "stag" string.

How can I do this in MongoDB without aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) operator which returns `-1` if a phrase isn't contained within a string:

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$img", "stag" ] }, -1 ] } })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0uklJTzUO3X)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match), `^` this will match from beginning of the string,

```
db.collection.find({
  img: {
    $not: { $regex: /^stag/ }
  }
})
```